# Space on top of div for unknown reason

Tags: html, space, css-tables

I'm working on a website and am finally almost done. I just have one problem. The table-cell on the right side (chalkboard) has a space on the top of it and I cant figure out for the life of how to get rid of it. It was fine until I put the pictures to the left of it.

To the best of my knowledge because they are in separate div's.

Can someone please help? Thank you!

The URL is thecheesepatch.com

Comment: I really prefer the Chrome debugger for inspecting things like this. You can make changes "on the fly" easily and see what is causing things to happen. (in this case it is "right-container: vertical-align:top;")

Comment: I was using it but this was my first time using a table-cell and wasn't aware of the vertical-align function, i'm still somewhat of a noob.

Answer (score 2):

Your `.right-container` is set to display as a table-cell and vertically aligning to the bottom. Assign this attribute to `.right-container` and you're good to go:

```
.right-container { 
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try setting `vertical-align:top;` to the table style. and `margin:0;`

Answer (score 0):

The `.right-container` is displayed as a `table-cell` and no vertically alignment set.

Assign the vertical alignment to `.right-container` and it will works as supposed:

```
.right-container { 
  vertical-align: top;
}
```